# PHPToolKit 2023_1 Uncaught SoapFault exception malformed syntax

Tags: netsuite, netsuite-rest-api, php-toolkit

I'm trying to use the latest PHPToolKit (2023_1) to read/update some records but am having an issue right out of the gate.  When trying to look up a contact with their email address, I'm getting the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception:
> [soapenv:Server.userException] The request could not be understood by
> the server due to malformed syntax. in
> /var/www/phpinclude/PHPToolkit_2023_1/PHPToolkit/NSPHPClient.php:296

The code causing this is below.  I've used this code before to test connections/execution with Netsuite before and it has worked fine.  In fact, it works fine if I use netsuite-php (https://github.com/netsuitephp/netsuite-php), but that uses namespaces and quite frankly, I'm not a good enough programmer to fully understand that and had issues trying to create functions to take care of tasks that I need to do in multiple scripts.

```
$recordRef = new RecordRef();
$recordRef->internalId = '-6'; //Internal ID for a customer is -2, contact is -6
$contactSearch = new ContactSearch(); //use CustomerSearch() for a customer
$contactSearchBasic = new ContactSearchBasic();//SearchRecordBasic
$contactSearchBasic->email = new SearchStringField();
$contactSearchBasic->email->searchValue = 'someone@somewhere.com';
$contactSearchBasic->email->operator = SearchStringFieldOperator::is;
$contactSearch->basic = $contactSearchBasic;
$searchRequest = new searchRequest(); //% contains a searchRecord
$searchRequest->searchRecord = $contactSearch;
$searchResponse = $ns->search($searchRequest);
print_r ($searchResponse);
```

Google only returned one result of a person who seemed to be having the same issue, but there was no solution.  I looked thru many posts that might be similar, but no luck.  Usually I can follow the error message and locate the problem, but this message isn't pointing me anywhere.

Server is:

- CentOS Stream 8
- Apache 2.4.37
- PHP 7.4.33 (php-fpm)

If someone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.